# Load Page in Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, renderpartial

I am trying to use Wiselinks gem.

Jquery code:

`window.wiselinks = new Wiselinks("#wiselinks");`

views/layout/application.html.erb :

`<div id="wiselinks" style="width: 100%">
 <%= yield %>
 </div>`

Show page html code:

```
<div class="profile_bar"> 
    some code I want to keep after loading here 
</div>
<a href="/users/feed/<%= @user.id %>" data-push="true"> 
</a>
```

Now, the feed page is loaded in `#wiselinks` div and url is changed correctly.
But I would like to keep the profile bar div when loading different pages. I could use a partial but I will have to redo the same queries many times to get the data for the partial.

what is the best solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Did I understand? Can u use jquery.load method? http://api.jquery.com/load/ This will just load html code from other file into your div. Or do u want to use wiselinks gem?

Comment: No because jQuery.load does not change the url..

Comment: Ok, now I understood, sorry

Comment: @Phil you are partially correct, you would just need to add the usage of pushState to change the browser url, then implement a workaround using the hash for browsers that don't support pushState.

Comment: @KevinB That is possible. But that is not the best decision we can provide, I suppose :)

Comment: I have tried pushState. Actually, I tried it at first. But it seems when refreshing the page or back button there were some problems so I changed to use Wiselinks